# make acondition on sql database table

Tags: c#

pleaze i want the statement of how to make condition on a table in sql database
if this value exits or not if exit i want a speciefic condition to be executed for example show this column (which i want to know if it exist or not) in grid view
like this

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT tagType,[exit-Time],enterTime,name,[tag-id-st],[build-id],punish,[room-no]FROM Students,GateLogging WHERE GateLogging.tagType='student' AND Students.[tag-id-st]=GateLogging.tagID AND DATEDIFF(minute,enterTime,GETDATE())<10 ", MyConn);
```

i want to know if punish not null show message box says that

Comment: You might want to add a concrete example of what you mean - it isn't very clear (to me, at least)

Comment: I am concerned by the "PUNISH" column in this query. Can you explain the resultant action of this business rule? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the adapter to fill a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), you can check if the column value is null or not (the example checks the first row):

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && !DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows[0]["punish"]))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("punish is not null");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am thoroughly in awe of your ability to turn that question into a sensible answer.